# How to control ReactJS MUI table column height and width

Tags: reactjs

Recently I used ReactJS MUI Table component, but I feel it's height is too large for my project nature. I am unable to properly control cell width and height of MUI Table component. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to customize your tables in Material UI. [This page](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) goes over the recommended ways in detail.

For tables you can add `size='small'` to your `<TableCell>` components make your table cells smaller. Or to make the table extremely dense, you can add `padding='none'` to your `<TableCell>` components.

```
<TableCell size='small'>
```

More specifics about Material UI Tables can be [found here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#api).

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of aria-label="a dense table" that was added as attribute in Dense MUI table ?

Comment: @user1368974 not visible accessibility name of the element. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label